# Locus of Control Test Results

Tags: data-request

I am looking for at least 1000 observations of locus of control tests like this [one](http://psychologytoday.tests.psychtests.com/bin/transfer?req=MTF8MTMxN3wxNDQ3MjQ2OHwxfDE=&refempt=) or this [one](http://psychologia.co/locus-of-control/). I need what each person answered for each question and ideally their demographics. This is highly unlikely but also metadata on them as they filled out the test would be amazing, for example how long it took to answer each question and other data points. Where can I find this data?

I would like it to be this data set but another large data set of personality test results would also be helpful.